# Add also the empty rows in a data frame construction

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

I want to construct a data frame based on two data frames

Here it is an example

```
#toy example
name <- c("Li", "Pedro", "Dave")
age <- c(20, 30, 40)
d1 <- cbind.data.frame(name, age)

name <- c("Pedro", "Dave", "Grace")
fav_col <- c("red", "blue", "yellow")
lastname <- c("Sanchez", "Stone", "Flint")
fav_food <- c("pizza", "hamburguers", "salad")
d2 <- cbind.data.frame(name, fav_col, lastname, fav_food)

d1$name <- as.character(d1$name)
d2$name <- as.character(d2$name)

cols <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(d1)) {
  some <- dplyr::filter(d2, name==d1$name[i])
  cols <- rbind.data.frame(cols, data.frame(some$name, some$fav_col,   some$fav_food))
}
```

Doing this I am obtaining a data frame called "cols" and looks like this:

```
         some.name   some.fav_col   some.fav_food
          Pedro           red          pizza
          Dave            blue         hamburguers
```

But what I want is

```
         some.name   some.fav_col      some.fav_food
          NA(or empty)    NA(or empty)  Na(or empty)
          Pedro           red             pizza
          Dave            blue            hamburguers
```

The first iteration when i = 1 must produce an empty exit because there is no Li in the second data frame, and I want this empty space in my data frame. Do you know how I could get this?

At the end I want to add the second and third columns of "cols" to "d1" to get:

```
        name     age  fav_col       fav_food
        Li       20   NA (or empty)  NA (or empty)
        Pedro    30   red            pizza
        Dave     40   blue           hamburguers
```

Also **I don't** want the empty spaces that the second data frame could produce like this:

```
       name    age  fav_col     fav_food
        Li     20     NA          NA
        Pedro  30     red         pizza
        Dave   40     blue        hamburguers
        Grace  NA     yellow      salad
```

I just want to merge the tables keeping only the names of the first data frame and add the two extra columns. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union_all` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- union_all(d1, d2) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% # only required when your text columns are
  group_by(name) %>%                     # identified as factor and not character.
  summarise_all(max, na.rm = TRUE) %>%   # Because max only works on numeric or char
  ungroup    

df

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   name    age fav_col lastname
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   
# 1 Dave    40. blue    Stone   
# 2 Li      20. NA      NA      
# 3 Pedro   30. red     Sanchez
```

To get your desired output, you can add `drop_na` to the chain.

```
df %>% select(name, fav_col) %>% drop_na

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   name  fav_col
#   <chr> <chr>  
# 1 Dave  blue   
# 2 Pedro red
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I could maintain the order as it is in the first column? I am going to edit my question to add a couple of specifications.

Comment: @EricGonzález, you can add an index and sort on that column to maintain row order.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, and I added paste and collapse just in case that someone needs to add results from different cells in just one.

```
 f_add_col <- function(vec) {
 add_col <- dplyr::filter(d2, name==vec[1])
 return (paste(add_col$fav_col, collapse = "|"))
}

 cbind.data.frame(d1, fav_col=apply(d1, 1, f_add_col))
```

Then I did the same for the column fav_food.